# Third Y Axis Mathematica

Tags: plotting, graphics

I was wondering what's the best way to create a plot with three data sets with 3 separate y axes. The best I can do is plot my three data sets onto one plot, overlay the frames for 2 of them and then create a third y-axis with Mathematica's AxisObject function. Here is my code below:

```
n = 65;

plotA = 
  ListPlot[newL8, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False, 
  Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}}, 
  FrameStyle -> {{Thick, Black}, {Thick, Red}, {Thick, 
     Black}, {Thick, Black}}, 
  FrameTicks -> {None, None, None, None}, ImageSize -> 400, 
  PlotRange -> All, ImagePadding -> {{40, 40}, {30, 30}}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"L = 8"}];
plotB = 
   ListPlot[newL64, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   PlotRange -> {{2.3, 2.9}, {0, 10}}, Axes -> False, 
   Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}}, FrameTicks -> All , 
   FrameLabel -> {None, None,
      None, None}, FrameStyle -> {Thick, Thick, Thick, Blue}, 
   ImageSize -> 400, PlotRange -> All, 
   ImagePadding -> {{40, 40}, {30, 30}}, PlotLegends -> {"L = 64"}];

plotC] = 
   ListPlot[newL256, PlotStyle -> ColorData[n, "ColorList"], 
   PlotRange -> {{2.3, 2.9}, {0, 40}}, Axes -> False, 
   Frame -> {{False, False}, {False, False}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {None, None, None, None}, 
   FrameLabel -> {None, None, None, None}, ImageSize -> 400, 
   PlotRange -> All, ImagePadding -> {{40, 40}, {30, 30}}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"L = 256"}];

yAxis256 = 
  Graphics[AxisObject[{"Vertical", 75, {-2, 40}}], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 0}, {46, 10}}, 
  AxesStyle -> 
  Directive[Thickness[0.25], {ColorData[n, "ColorList"]}, 
  Ticks -> Automatic, TickPositions -> {0, 40, 2}], 
  ImageMargins -> {{35, 5}, {10, 2}}];

combinedplots = Overlay[{plotA], plotB], plotC], yAxis256}, Alignment -> Left, ImageSize -> Large]
```

What I get is this:

[image]

I cannot figure out how to make the tick marks appear on the third axis.

Please advise & thanks in advance!

Comment: My suggestion is: don't. If the data are related in some way, then scale them appropriately so that it makes *sense* to put them on the same graph (perhaps by normalizing, either by dividing by the maximum value or the integral under the curves, or something). Otherwise, put them on different graphs. This is very much my personal opinion about the presentation of data, and I know that other people feel differently about it, but by thinking about this, you might find a better way to display the data and tell the story you're trying to tell! That said, i'll look for a solution.

Comment: Have you explored the [MultiaxisArrangement](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MultiaxisArrangement.html) ?

Comment: I unfortunately have Mathematica 12.3.1-- I think MultiaxisArrangement was introduced in Mathematica 13, if I'm not mistaken